# Python Request for JSON file returns None

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}

d = {"query": "/api/v2/details/ip/", "query_entry": "41.219.127.69"}


r = requests.get("https://talosintelligence.com/sb_api/query_lookup/", 
data = d, headers=header)
```

When I run the same result from the main site "talosintelligence.com" and look at the network counsel, that exact URL is responds with a JSON file but a `get` request from python returns `None`.

[image: Screenshot of page]

Comment: I think it may be using a session cookie to confirm that the query is coming from the form.

Comment: There's a cookie callesd `talos_website_session`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by setting the `referer` header..

```
import requests
sess = requests.session()
ip_addr = "41.219.127.69"
ret = sess.get('https://talosintelligence.com/sb_api/query_lookup', data={"query": "/api/v2/details/ip/", "query_entry": ip_addr, "offset": 0, "order": "ip asc"}, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.31 Safari/537.36', 'referer': 'https://talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=' + ip_addr})
```

Comment: Thank you!! Just adding "referer" to the header resolved it.